# Number of $5$-Sylows of a simple group of order $660$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a simple group of order $660$. I am trying to find $n_5$ - the number of Sylow $5$-subgroups of $G$. 
I have easily proved that $n_5 \in \{1, 6, 11, 66\}$ using Sylow Theorems. Besides, I have concluded that if cannot be $1$ or $6$, but I don't know how to exclude the other option (so the result will follow).

Comment: I imagine $G$ must be $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_{11})$ in which case the answer ends up being $n_5 = 66$, but I don't know how to prove it just from the Sylow theorems, which I imagine is the intended approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$G$ must have $12$ Sylow $11$-subgroups. Consider its action by conjugation on this set of $12$ subgroups.

The normalizer of a Sylow $11$-subgroup has order $55$ and an element $g$ of order $5$ must consist of two $5$-cycles.

To see this, suppose that the $11$-cycle is $h=(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)$, with fixed point $1$. Then $\langle h \rangle$ is normalized by the $g$, and so $g$ most also fix $1$ and at least one other point, say $2$

If $g^{-1}hg=h$, then $gh$ has order $55$, which is clearly impossible. So $g^{-1}hg = h^i$ for some $i$ with $2 \le i \le 10$ (and in fact we must have $i^5 \equiv 1 \bmod 11$). Now we can see from the conjugation rule for permutations that $g$ must consist of two $5$-cycles. For example, if $i=4$, then $h^4=(2,6,10,3,7,11,4,8,12,5,9)$ and $g = (3,6,7,11,5)(4,10,12,9,8)$.

Alternatively, you could argue that if $g$ fixes another point, say $k$, then, since $h^{k-1}$ maps $2$ to $k$, so $g$ must centralize $h^{k-1}$, which also generates $\langle h \rangle$, so $g$ centralizes $h$, which is impossible.

Now $G$ is doubly transitive of order $660 = 12 \times 11 \times 5$, so $\langle g \rangle$ is the stabilizer of the two points $1$ and $2$. The normalizer of $\langle g \rangle$ must stabilize the set of fixed points of $g$, which is $\{1,2\}$, and so this normalizer has order $5$ or $10$. Hence it must be $10$, and there are $66$ Sylow $5$-subgroups.

Note that there is a group with all of these properties, namely ${\rm PSL}(2,11)$, and we are looking at its action on the projective line.

It would also be possible to rule out the case $|{\rm Syl}_5(G)| = 11$ with a similar argument, by considering the induced action on $11$ points and getting a contradiction. Interestingly, ${\rm PSL}(2,11)$ does act on $11$ points, also doubly transitively, but its point stabilizer is $A_5$ rather than the normalizer of a Sylow $5$-subgroup.

Comment: Sorry, why can't an element of order $5$ consist of a $5$-cycle and $7$ fixed points? I also don't understand how you conclude that the normalizer has order $10$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I have added lots more detail to my proof.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but I'm afraid I still don't fully understand. 1) Why is $g^{-1} hg = h$ "clearly" impossible? 2) I get that if $g^{-1} hg \neq h$ then $g$ acts on $\langle h \rangle$ as an element of order $5$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/11)^{\times}$, and I think I can use that to show that it must consist of two $5$-cycles, but why does this imply that $G$ acts doubly transitively on the Sylow $11$-subgroups?

Comment: Oh, I think I see double transitivity now. Suppose $i \neq j$ are the indices of two Sylow $11$-subgroups; WLOG $i = 1$, so we can consider the action of some nontrivial $h$ in the corresponding Sylow, which fixes $1$ and acts by an $11$-cycle on the other Sylows. Then acting by $h$ we can arrange $j = 2$. So now the stabilizer of an ordered pair of distinct points must be a subgroup of order $5$. Okay, I'm happy with that part of the argument now! I guess we get double transitivity whenever the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups is $p + 1$.

Comment: Oh, okay, where you wrote $g^4$ you meant $h^4$. Okay, that's much clearer, I buy that  if $ghg^{-1} \neq h$ then $g$ acts by two $5$-cycles now. I still don't know why there can't be an element of order $55$ but we can instead just argue that the centralizer of $h$ in $S_{12}$ is $\langle h \rangle$ and so doesn't contain an element of order $5$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan An element of order $55$ would have to contain either a $55$-cycle or a $5$-cycle and an $11$-cycle, so the smallest $S_n$ containing such an element is $S_{16}$.

Comment: I guess I have spent a lot of my life doing research involving finite simple groups, which at the more elementary level involves copious proofs that there is no simple group of order $n$ for various $n$, and certain types of argument come up so frequently that they become totally familiar. The one here is reasonably straightforward as they go. With more difficult numbers they can get much more intricate. Proving there is no simple group of order 720 is particularly challenging - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3779512/)

Comment: ah, of course, thanks! I think I'm happy with the whole argument now. I've worked through some exercises like this but I don't think they've ever required this much outside of the Sylow theorems.