# No simple group of order 720, again

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

In his Notes on Group Theory, 2019 edition (http://pdvpmtasgaon.edu.in/uploads/dptmaths/AnotesofGroupTheoryByMarkReeder.pdf p. 83 and ff.)
Mark Reeder gives a proof of the non-existence of simple groups of order 720.

Here : ([No simple group of order 720](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3779512/no-simple-group-of-order-720) ) I asked for a clarification about a statement at the beginning of the proof and I got it. (Thanks again to David A. Craven.)

I have another problem, perhaps more serious, at the end of the proof. M. Reeder proves that if $G$ is a simple group of order 720, if $s$ is an involution (element of order 2) of $G$, then $C_{G}(s)$ is a Sylow 2-subgroup of $G$ and that if $s$ and $t$ are two differents involutions of $G$, then $C_{G}(s)$ and $C_{G}(t)$ are different. So far, so good. A little further, M. Reeder says : "Since $s$ is contained in just one Sylow 2-subgroup, namely $C_{G}(s)$ (...)". I don't understand how that can be deduced from what precedes.

I must say that I am skeptical about the possibility of proving this in the frame of M. Reeder's proof, for the following reason. After proving that (for a simple group $G$ of order 720), $G$ has exactly ten Sylow 3-subgroups, that these Sylow 3-subgroups are non-cyclic and intersect pairwise trivially, M. Reeder seems to derive a contradiction from only the following properties :

s1 : $G$ is a group (I don't say "simple group") of order 720 ;

s2 : $G$ has exactly ten Sylow 3-subgroups ;

s3 :  these Sylow 3-subgroups are non-cyclic ;

s4 :  these Sylow 3-subgroups  intersect pairwise trivially ;

s5 : $G$ has no element of order 6 ;

s6 : every involution of $G$ normalizes at least two  Sylow 3-subgroups of $G$ ;

s7 : $G$ has several Sylow 2-subgroups.

(M. Reeder uses another property to prove that some given subgroups of $G$ are isomorphic to $Q_{8}$, but he notes that this fact plays no real role.)

Now, properties s1 to s7 are not contradictory, because the group $M_{10}$ possesses them. (By the way, properties s1 to s7 are not independent : s3 can be deduced from s1, s2 and s5, using the N/C lemma.)

My question is : do you see how the statement "$s$ is contained in just one Sylow 2-subgroup, namely $C_{G}(s)$" can be proved in the frame of Mark Reeder's proof ? Thanks in advance.

Note : I wrote up M. Reeder's proof by breaking it down into simple elements and indicating, for each element, the minimum hypotheses. If anyone is interested, I can post this work here. I can also post a proof that $M_{10}$ possesses properties  s1 to s7.

Comment: I don't think that you can deduce from s1 - s7 that every involution lies in a unique Sylow 2-subgroup, because $M_{10}$ satisfies s1 - s7, and that property does not hold in $M_{10}$. In $M_{10}$, every involution $s$ lies in exactly 5 Sylow 2-subgroups, one of which is $C_G(s)$.

Comment: @ Derek Holt Thanks for this comment. Yes, if  every involution lied in a unique Sylow 2-subgroup, this, with s7, would lead to a contradiction (since the number of the Sylow 2-subgroups should be congruent to 1 mod 16, wich is impossible for a divisor of 45 different from 1), thus since properties s1 to s7 are satisfied by M10, we know that wet cannot deduce from s1 to s7 that every involution lies in a unique Sylow 2-subgroup. But Mark Reeder seems to think that it is possible. (He gives no other reason to justify the problematic assertion.)